# Chamada de método dentro uma classe

Tags: java

Tenho esta parte do meu código em que chamo uma classe para adicionar '0' à um grupo de caracteres que tem que ter obrigatoriamente 4 caracteres.

```
StringTokenizer frase = new StringTokenizer(IMEIstring,".");
String first = frase.nextToken();
if(first.length()<4){
    AddOh instancia = new AddOh();
    String primeiro = instancia.AddZero(first);
    first = primeiro;
}
```

Porém ele não chama a classe, dá erro. No Logcat nao aparece nada e quando faço o Debug fica como o seguinte: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o código completo da classe AddOh: (Ah, se eu coloco ele dentro da classe principal como uma função interna e tento chamá-lo sem instância também não roda)

```
package com.example.minhaslicencasnobre;

public class AddOh {
    public String AddZero(String pedaco) {
        String fim = null;
        String[] H = null, finish, temp;
        int i,j=0;

        finish = new String[4];
        temp = new String[4];

        if(pedaco.length()<4){
            int tam =  pedaco.length();

            for(i=0;i<pedaco.length();i++)
                H[i] = pedaco.substring(i, i+1);

            for(i=3;i>=0;i--){
                if(i<tam){
                    temp[i]= H[j];
                    j++;
                }else
                    temp[i]="0";    
            }
            j=temp.length-1;
            for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                finish[i] = temp[j];
                j--; 
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<=finish.length;i++){
            fim = fim + finish[i];
        }
        return fim;
    }
}
```

Comment: Só para entender: você tem uma string qualquer e quer que esta seja completada com zeros à direita? Como se tivesse **A2** e voltasse **A200**?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues ela voltaria como 00A2. No método tem uma parte que volta como A200 mas depois é colocado corretamente como 00A2.

Comment: É possível que essa *string* contenha espaço? Se não, acredito que pode ser feito de outra forma ao invés de todo esse código.

Comment: Não @PauloRodrigues tem que ser somente os 4 caracteres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi da sua pergunta e de acordo com os comentários, acredito que a solução pode ser bem simplificada utilizando a própria classe [`String`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html).

Experimente algo assim:

```
first = String.format("%4s", first).replace(' ', '0')
```

Assim você terá um "*padding*" à esquerda na sua *string* e logo em seguida substituído por zeros cada um dos espaços.

Veja um exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/G6OuVu).

Comment: Puxa vida, apanhei tanto para a solução ser tão simples assim rs Muito obrigada @PauloRodrigues